# Extract content from a page

Tags: html, text-extraction

I need to recognize content in a page - to do something as so http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/text/ (I need to get the HTML so I cant use this API)

What logic can I use to accomplish this? (Coding language is not matter)

Here what I did (with a good result) - needs a lot more fixes...

1. Find the most text in page so don't have a breaking tags - ignore inline tags (span, b, etc...)
2. Go up one level and count breaking tags (br, p, div, etc...)
3. Go up another level and count tags
4. Compare tags count from step 2 with step 3
5. If there is a lot of different we stop here - if not we go to step 3

Comment: You can use predefined parsers or write this logic yourself. Maybe just work with the DOM-Obejct of some languages (PHP or JS i.e.). I did something similar in Ruby with Hpricot, that was really comfortable, too. -- I guess the laguange really depends on what you want to do (what do you mean with more advanced?) and if other parameters have an impact (clientside, serverside, possible executables).

Comment: why don't you take a look at there source?

Comment: Please show more of your code.  This is a complex question.  Comments like "I need to go more advance" are only good if you indicate exactly what that requirement is".  We're happy to help but you have to put more info into the question to get better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for [the Boilerpipe library](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/). It is a comprehensive solution.

Using the Boilerpipe library, you can specify the output as HTML. So you get the main content(the article) while still preserving its HTML tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot - do you know a lib for C# so do the same? If not I will need to port it 2 C# or learn how to embed java...

Comment: No. I'd put this in a web service and call it from C#.

Comment: There is a port to C# called [NBoilerpipe](https://github.com/oganix/NBoilerpipe)

Answer (score 2):

Another good alternative would be to use [Goose](https://github.com/GravityLabs/goose/wiki).

It allows more fields(published date, author, main image in article and a few more) than Boilerpipe (title, content)

Answer (score 0):

You need a parser for navigate the DOM, in the NuGet packages you can find some helpful parser tools like [this](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Sudheer sorry, i'm new about Stack answers! (and i can't comment to questions yet).

Comment: .no problem.. SO is moderated to keep answers well described- link answers are often closed when they pop up in review queue's